# `docker-compose build` not finding file or directory after COPY

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose build --no-cache` fails with this error:

```
 ---> Running in f62172d2e9f9
Removing intermediate container f62172d2e9f9
 ---> db5896c4aac5
Step 10/16 : COPY ./rclone/install.sh /data/rclone/
 ---> e659d60665cf
Step 11/16 : COPY ./rclone.conf /root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf
 ---> 61e3b9107870
Step 12/16 : RUN chmod +x ./rclone/install.sh
 ---> Running in 9c5eead9141b
Removing intermediate container 9c5eead9141b
 ---> 42fefac58542
Step 13/16 : RUN ./rclone/install.sh
 ---> Running in fbadefae8a57
': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c ./rclone/install.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.22-alpine3.11

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --update python make g++\
   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN apk add --update python make g++\
   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN apk add nginx


WORKDIR /data

COPY ./rclone/install.sh /data/rclone/

COPY ./rclone.conf /root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf

RUN chmod +x ./rclone/install.sh
RUN ./rclone/install.sh

COPY . /data/project/NodeApp

RUN chmod +x /data/project/NodeApp/scripts/.supervisor.sh

CMD /data/project/NodeApp/scripts/.supervisor.sh
```

Any ideas as to what's causing this and how to fix it? rclone is in the root folder. I've reviewed previously answered questions about docker-compose not working, and otherwise researched this issue and haven't found much on it.

Any advice would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your Dockerfile ```/data``` is the root dir

Comment: @MargachChris, right, but is it not getting copied into `/data`? I'm only recently getting into bash commands.

Comment: That odd-looking error message often suggests a file has gotten copied in with DOS line endings.  Can you check that the file has Unix line endings?

Comment: The `chmod +x ./rclone/install.sh` command succeeds, so this suggests to me that `./rclone/install.sh` is a valid path. The `No such file or directory` error might be coming from something the `install.sh` script is running. Try adding `set -x` to the start of the `install.sh` to confirm if the script is actually run, and where the script might be failing. You can also confirm the script is present by running `ls -l ./rclone/install.sh` just after your `chmod` command.

Comment: @DavidMaze The line endings are `\n` and `\r\n`

Comment: @ShaneBishop I tried both `set -x` and `set -vx` and it returns: `./rclone/install.sh: set: line 1: illegal option -`

Comment: If it's a Linux container, there shouldn't be any `\r` in the file at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze it is a Linux container! Thank you for this info. How do I go about removing them?

Comment: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) has all kinds of suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DavidMaze helped me figure this out. It was erroring on `\r` line endings because the files were converted to DOS when downloaded from GitHub. Running `dos2unix` fixed the problem, and we added a `.gitattributes` so that the line endings are no longer converted. See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for more solutions.